# How do I integrate Firebase with Ionic?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

The tutorials I've come across are not clear enough to me for some reason. 
Firebase offers an iOS sdk, Android sdk and a Javascript web Sdk. Am I supposed to use the javascript sdk? I'm using ionic because I want to build a hybrid app for both android and iOS, so the sdk's for a native OS are not useful to me.

I just want to make sure I'm picking the right thing with the javascript web sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire is an open source library maintained by the Firebase team which provides a binding for Firebase in AngularJS projects. Since Ionic is based on AngularJS, so it suite anyway.